# Setting DataGridViewColumn.ReadOnly to "false" causes an extra Paint() pass

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, paint

I've been overriding `DataGridViewTextBoxCell.Paint()` to paint contents for all of my cells. Before they were all ReadOnly but now I need the user to input data into them. As I discovered, once you allow for it by setting `DataGridViewColumn.ReadOnly` to "false" and specifying the bound `DataPropertyName`, the system starts Painting the cell over my overriden `Paint()` call. I would not mind it for the case when I am actively editing the cell, but the problem is, it is even painting the cells with this extra pass when the cursor is actualy away from them. Even worse, when the grid is not focused, the selected cell is NOT painted with an extra pass. How do I locate and override the extra `Paint()` pass?

Comment: I would guess that the system wants to display the read-only look or the reular one.. And the editing control is not painted anyway, or rather it os but it s a separate control. you can grab a reference of it and try to set it to ownerdraw but textboxes are a bit resistive..

Comment: How do you do the latter (grab a reference of a textbox)? And one more thing: I understand, that when you are entering the text, the cell should be painted in a specific way, but why does it re-paint it when the CurrentCell is NOT on the painted cell?

Comment: To grabe and use the editcontrol: `TextBox editBox = null;
        private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
                     DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            editBox = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (editBox != null) editBox.Text += "§";
        }` - It probably makes sure to catch all cells..

Comment: Ok but how do you override Paint() method for it?

Comment: You could do that but TextBoxes will not honor the event I'm afraid. To do it add this soemwhere, eg the form load: `editBox.Paint+=editBox_Paint; void editBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, e.ClipRectangle);
}`. But as I said it will not work because TextBox is rather old and resilient to any manipulation of its looks..